# Where pointer points when we change the content of pointer?

Tags: c

When we declare pointer for example

> char *p;

and then we do

> *p = 'a';

then what is the value of **p**

I mean where **p** points?

Is it write **'a'** in some arbitrary memory location and then the pointer i.e. **p** points to that memory location?

***P.S. - Sorry in advance because my English is not upto that mark. Edits are welcome :)***

Comment: Some random memory location. It's undefined behavior.

Comment: If `p` is defined at file scope, you've tried to assign via a null pointer.  That's undefined behaviour, but usually causes your program to crash.  If `p` is defined inside a function, then it is uninitialized, so it doesn't point anywhere specific, and you attempt to write to an indeterminate location.  Nothing good happens.  Initialize your pointer (to a non-null value) before assigning via the pointer.

Comment: Dude, you are free to test it.

Comment: Show a [mcve]. In the snippets shown, you don't "change" **the pointer**. You don't even initialise it or assign it an initial value. This question definitively would not have arisen if you learned the langauge basics in a structured way, not watched obscure YT videos or online tutorials (or skipped chapters in your textbook).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The assignment `*p = 'a'` puts a value in the place where `p` points, but it does not assign a value to the pointer `p`.

When you use `*p = 'a'`, the pointer `p` must already have a value. It is your job as a programmer to assign it a value by allocating space with `malloc` or by setting `p` to point to an existing object that you wish to change, as with `p = &x`, where `x` is defined earlier.

If you use `*p = 'a'` without previously assigning a behavior to `p`, then the behavior is not defined by the C standard. Common results of this include:

- The code acts as if `p` has an effectively random value, perhaps the value of some bits that were left over from previous work in the memory where the new `p` was created. Then `*p = 'a'` may write `'a'` into an unexpected place, and this can cause your program to malfunction in various ways. Or `p` may point to unallocated memory, and `*p = 'a'` will cause your program to crash.
- During optimization, a compiler may recognize that `p` is uninitialized in some or all circumstances when `*p = 'a'` is executed. Due to the construction of modern optimizers, this may cause the compiler to eliminate the entire code path on which `*p = 'a'` appears, in the applicable circumstances. This can cause an entire section of your program to vanish.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest you to look into this [article](https://edoras.sdsu.edu/doc/c/pointers-1.2.2/) here in order to better understand the concept of pointers.

I'll dig into the first example with int:

we have

```
int foo;
```

and then we declare

```
int *foo_ptr = &foo;
```

which is jut like your `char` example above.

`foo_ptr` is declared as a pointer to int. **We have initialised it to point to foo**..

now, Think of every variable as a box. foo is a box that is sizeof(int) bytes in size. The location of this box is its address. When you access the address, you actually access the contents of the box it points to.

when you declare:

```
char *p;
```

and then:

```
*p = 'a';
```

you do not point to an address, `*p` is a defined point in memory, meaning static allocation and it is a read-only section of memory.
any attempt to change `*p` will result in **Undefined Behavior** because of the above.

Comment: please consider replacing the word `static` in your last paragraph with something else that gets the same semantic meaning across.  If for no other reason than `static` has a very specific meaning in C, which could possibly cause some confusion.